# Adding keyboard layout in Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I'm currently using the latest version of Linux Mint and I'm trying to install a new keyboard layout (NOTE: Add a new one, not change to one that's already installed). The layout I'm trying to add can be found at this website: http://arjenvankol.com/dvorak.php. I have tried to follow the instructions included in the file but the information seems to be outdated or just not compatible with my version of Linux Mint.

So, basically, can someone give a detailed explanation on how to add this keyboard layout?